# Can dictionary/json like objects be created using eval in splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to do something like this

```
publishedToIntegrator=if(raw!="", {"value":"True","time":_time}, {"value":"False","time":null})
```

Is this allowed? I couldn't find any documentation/resources supporting if we can have dictionary data types in the variables we create in splunk.

Comment: Why would you want to create JSON in a `eval` statement?

Making multivalue fields often makes sense.

But JSON (or JSON-like data)? 

What problem are you trying to solve - there's most likely a much better way to approach it than what you're proposing :)

Comment: I want to display some information in tabular form. For one of the columns, i want to display 2 information : boolean True/False ie was the column's condition satisfied and _time ie when was the condition satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequential `eval` statements to make/overwrite fields in Splunk like this:

```
| eval publishedToIntegrator=if(len(raw)>0,"True","False")
| eval time=if(len(publishedToIntegrator)<5,_time,NULL)
```

However, knowing what you're trying to accomplish will help us answer better.

#### edit to incorporate comment:

```
| eval publishedToIntegrator=if(len(raw)>0,"True "+strftime(_time,"%c"),"False"
```

or

```
| eval publishedToIntegrator=if(len(raw)>0,"True","False")
| eval _time=if(len(publishedToIntegrator)<5,_time,NULL)
| table publishedToIntegrator _time
```